# AWS replace or assign IAM instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-iam

I'm using Ansible to automate the management of existing hosts. I'd like the playbook to be as comprehensive as possible and to that end I'm attempting to automate the creation and assignment of IAM roles to the instances.

I saw that it's possible to assign roles to new instances, which is not exactly my use case: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_module.html#parameter-instance_profile_name

This post recommends using the aws client via the shell module for existing instances:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/ah4jcc/how_do_you_attach_an_iam_role_onto_the_ec2/

But, the problem with that is the aws client supports two commands:

`aws ec2 replace-iam-instance-profile-association`

`aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile`

This means I need to first check if a profile has been assigned to the instance before choosing one of these commands. To perform that check, I need to use a third command:

`aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations`

All of this logic makes the playbook quite messy.

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this help? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/attach-replace-ec2-instance-profile/  aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations

Comment: @Anton thanks! i saw that already -- that's what i mean by first checking the profiles associated with the instance. Edited my answer to include that bit. Cheers!

Comment: May be ignore the error raised by `aws ec2 replace-iam-instance-profile-association` if the profile is already attached? Bad programming though.

Comment: @Asdfg do you mean run both `replace` and `associate`, knowing that one will always work and one will always fail? that's actually not so bad...

Comment: @matthewatabet: Yeah. You can do that. I was assuming `replace` will take care of associating the IAM role if no IAM role is associated. Or may be do `replace` and if there is an error do `associate` and if still there is an error, something else is wrong.